# create a temporary account in svn

Tags: svn

Is it possible for subversion to create an account which is only available in period of time ?

Because the internal audit rule in our company, the source code in subversion is only accessible in 2 days each application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any job creation software like "Jenkins" to schedule a job for 2 days and automate svn access rules from there.